# Add Outlook Explorer ribbon in a Outlook 2007 add in?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm writing a Outlook 2007 add in which works in Outlook 2007 AND 2010(one build is supposed to work for both versions) - everything works perfect right now except for one thing:

Outlook 2007 doesn't have a ribbon in the main Outlook Explorer window, but Outlook 2010 does.

If I create a new Ribbon (Visual Designer) I can't choose Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer as my RibbonType för the Ribbon, so is there any way I can add a ribbon to the Outlook Explorer window in Outlook 2010 from a Outlook 2007-add in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multitarget like this, I believe you have to fall back to the using IExtensibility, and intercept the GetCustomUI callback yourself to supply (or not supply) any ribbon modification xml.

At least, that's what I had to do with my addin that targeted versions 2000-2010 of Word, Excel, and PPT (I also supported Outlook, but there wasn't any UI stuff in my addin for outlook so I'm not sure there). More difficult, but more flexible in what you can support.